# How to mavenize a Scala / Akka / Play project?

Tags: scala, maven, playframework-2.0, sbt, akka

I have a small project which uses Scala, Akka and Play combined. The way I set it up is the old-school way: download everything and link. I would like instead to mavenize the whole thing. Could you recommend me a clear, specific guide to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this thread https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-user/fXq84tp8R38/uUw24W4Gi4AJ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use Maven - use SBT - it's the build tool of choice.

Note maven is now squarely in the thoughtworks radar Hold section meaning nobody should be building new projects on it if you trust Fowler's advice: http://www.thoughtworks.com/radar

Play comes with sbt under the hood already so you shouldn't have to look to far from where you are now:
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Build

Comment: what a hillarious answer. Actually it isn't an answer at all. OP asked "how to build with Maven" and you answer "maven is evil" (we all know that, yawn)

Comment: That's actually true - this isn't a helpful answer in respect to the question but the poster seems unaware that sbt is used to build/run/package play applications and is integrated into play already.

Comment: True. SBT is the de facto standard in the Scala world